# PostgreSQL COPY FROM PROGRAM using ImageMagick

Tags: postgresql, copy

I have 1000 images, and thanks to ImageMagick I can retrieve a lot of information regarding an image by writing `"identify -verbose [PATH OF IMAGE]"` in the cmd.

I installed ImageMagick with 'legacy on' , to access individual tools rather than the monolithic version of the library.

If I write "`identify -verbose C:\\temp\\cbirCorel10k\\1.jpg`" in the command prompt it works perfectly, outputting data I need.

My problem is when I insert this code into PROGRAM of PostgreSQL like so :

```
copy manyline(txt)
from program 'identify -verbose C:\\temp\\cbirCorel10k\\1.jpg'
```

It gives me this error, and please note that I ***do*** have permissions on the image and parent folders to be accessed:

> ERROR: program "identify -verbose C:\temp\cbirCorel10k\1.jpg"
>   failed SQL state: 38000   Detail: child process exited with exit code
>   1

I want that the output from that command line, is inputted into the table 'manyline' under column 'txt'.

Please note that the following code works well, but I want to make use of the PROGRAM function.

```
copy manyline(txt)
from 'C:\\temp\\something.txt'
```

[image: image file permissions]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The postgresql server needs permissions to run that program and read that file.  it usually runs under username `postgres` (unless they've changed that recently). this is a "service user" and can be hard to find in the windows GUI; especially on "home" editions of windows. I can't say for sure if granting `NETWORK SERVICE` access is enough.

easiest solution is to use the `psql` command-line interface and do

```
\copy manyline(txt) from program 'identify -verbose C:\\temp\\cbirCorel10k\\1.jpg'
```

`\copy` is a psql built-in which runs the command (opens the file etc) as the current user, instead of asking the server to run it.  this also works well where the server is not local.